# React Native - Improve our RN App launch time

Tags: android, performance, react-native

The project I was working is to use react native to create an Android app.

Following is the cold launch time in LG G7  release build

our React Native App(Android) launch is slow, I find the most time is costed in  jsbundle loaded

process and native create : 0.6s

the jsbundle load time : 2.1s

js render time : 0.35s

other time: 0.3s

total time: 3.5s ~ 4.5s

The slowest part is to wait react library to load the js bundle (2.2MB). Is the loading time looks normal? How can I improve the js bundle loading time? Thanks so much.

Comment: Testing on production or development?

Comment: Release version

Comment: Test on production

Comment: @chengliu Did you find a way to improve the launch time?